# using block of HttpClient.GetAsync does register cancellation token

Tags: c#, .net-core, cancellation-token

I've noticed an unexpected behaviour when trying to use cancellation token inside the using block of HttpClient.GetAsync() .

Namely, calling the cancellationTokenSource.Cancel() does not trigger the cancellation token inside this block.

As far as I know this code should throw OperationCancelledException and write out "Token cancelled" but it does not. Anybody got an idea why?

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
            var token = tokenSource.Token;

            Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                using (var response = await client.GetAsync("some_url"))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        while (true)
                        {
                            token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                        }
                    }
                    catch (OperationCanceledException ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Token cancelled");
                    }
                }
            });

            tokenSource.Cancel();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Perhaps the task is cancelled before it even starts

Comment: Does `await client.GetAsync` throw an exception?

Comment: Side note: don't use `HttpClient` itself in a `using` block

Comment: I bet that `client.GetAsync` method throws an exception. And since `Task.Run` does not await, this exception is swallowed.